# How does my parachain crowdloan pallet work with Slot Auction + Crowdfunding?

Tags: parachain, crowdloan, auctions, crowdfunding

My team has got our parachain crowdloan pallet working, thanks to 
[PureStake & Moonbeam](https://github.com/PureStake/crowdloan-rewards)

According to Polkadot and Moonbeam's [description of Crowdloans](https://medium.com/moonbeam-network/what-is-a-crowdloan-benefits-explanation-7c6540267617) and [example specs](https://medium.com/moonbeam-network/moonriver-crowdloan-what-you-need-to-know-7d918a0d7002), I think there must be some kind of Crowdfunding+Slot Auction going on somewhere before any Crowdloan can happen, right?

(as a Crowdloan just gives out reward tokens over certain time periods, but before this can happen the crowdfunding must be finished first, right?)

The thing is that I could not find such crowdfunding or auction source code in either Polkadot or Moonbeam repositories...

If such source code is hidden, then we can only trust Polkadot team to run Crowdfunding and Slot Auction for my team, is that correct?

More reference: https://medium.com/moonbeam-network/tagged/crowdloan

Comment: Please add links to where you are reading about things, for others to reference and understand context

Comment: references added. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the mechanism of rewards for participants in a crowdloan that exist on your parachain and the slot auctions and crowdloans that exist on the relay chain.

Relay chains has the slot mechanisms, including the crowdloan pallet in its' runtime, that is actually implemented alongside the relay chain runtimes here: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/tree/master/runtime/common/src

Parachains *may* implement other logic that looks at the state of the relay chain for information they then map to something on their parachain. Up to them and their community to decide.

Comment: does that mean my parachain's crowdloan pallet is not needed for me to run a crowdloan, because the Relay chain has crowdloan already?

Comment: "Parachains may implement other logic that looks at the state of the relay chain" is my next question... please have a look https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1801/how-to-get-relay-accounts-native-accounts-and-contributed-amounts-from-a-crowdl

Comment: The crowd loan pallet isn't required on parachians. This isn't really useful in the context of one, but perhaps only could be used as a reference to inform of logic that might inspire your work and inform how to generate those rewards from reading storages on the relay chain

Answer (score 4):

Everything running on Polkadot & Kusama is OSS, there is nothing "private" or "hidden" or deployed without the source being available:

[Crowdloans source](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/256d5db19585b469a8b0e2e2f22e86c2ae25785e/runtime/common/src/crowdloan/mod.rs#L1)

[Auctions source](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/256d5db19585b469a8b0e2e2f22e86c2ae25785e/runtime/common/src/auctions.rs#L1)

Comment: Thank you. Oh i see. it is just hard to find those details