# From the parachain, how to read the relay chain events of a current block?

Tags: parachain, events, crowdloan

From [this comment](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/how-does-my-parachain-crowdloan-pallet-work-with-slot-auction-crowdfunding#comment1697_1775) and [this question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2259/read-current-crowdloan-contributions),

There's a function for runtime-benchmarks to get all the [`events()`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L1403). And I want something similar that can be accessed from the parachain. Just events from the relay chain that occur in a certain block.
Is there a function for it?